# GRANT ADMINISTER Database Bulk Operations - Incorrect syntax near ADMINISTER

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to import a bacpac file to my SQL Server Express 2016.
An exception is thrown during the import with

```
GRANT ADMINISTER Database Bulk Operations TO [MyUser];
```

Returns:

> Incorrect syntax near 'ADMINISTER'.

I am running the import as the `sa` user. Later when I try to run the SQL line directly, the same error is thrown. What can I do to resolve this?

Update: SQL Server Express 2019 throws "is not supported on this version of SQL Server" on the same line

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) suggests that the syntax is correct on both 2016 and 2019 without mentioning the exact applicable edition (Windows or Linux, Express or others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says "`ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS` Applies to: SQL Database."

In the context of the docs "SQL Database" is Azure SQL DB. Not the SQL Server running on Windows/Linux. "SQL Database" always means Azure SQL Database. The docs simply use both interchangeably.